# Using a Search Cursor with a list

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

What I'm attempting to do is create a list of .dbf tables using a wildcard which I've managed to do. From there my goal is to search the list and extract the value of a specific field. This field only contains 1 row, the value will then be used to populate a field contained in another table which, I haven't begun to attempt yet.Below is a code snippet:

```
tableList05 = arcpy.ListTables("*_2005.dbf")
#for table05 in tableList05:
with arcpy.SearchCursor(tableList05, ['SUM'])as cursorFive:
    for row in cursorFive:
       print row
```

For now I'm simply trying to get those values to print before trying to manage how to copy them and update the records in an existing table. The error message I receive when I run this section of code tells me the .dbf tables don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

`tableList05' - assuming it isn't empty - contains a list of the filenames only. No path names

You need to set the workspace so Python knows where these tables are located:

Option 1:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = "<folder>"
```

Option 2:

```py
#The variable now contains absolute paths to the tables.
from os.path import join
tableList05 = [join("<folder>", tbl) for tbl in arcpy.ListTables("*_2005.dbf")]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, 10.1 and I did set the environment workspace, it is at the beginning of the code, I just didn't show it. I just tried re writing the code:            tableList05 = arcpy.ListTables("*_2005.dbf")
for table05 in tableList05:
    cursorFive = arcpy.SearchCursor(table05, ['SUM'])
    for row in cursorFive:
        print row Now I get the following text for the print statement: <geoprocessing row object object at 0x000000000DB90DB0>

Comment: Need to use row.getValue("Sum"). I'd suggest you move to the data access module though as it's faster and you might find it easier to use.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I think using your suggestions I may have come up with a more efficient way which doesn't require as much geoprocessing to complete the task as I couldn't get the .getValue statement to return the correct value.